# Increase camera view distance

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I wrote a small program just to see how OpenGL works with SFML:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(700,700),
        "OpenGL test", sf::Style::Default);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);   

    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time time;
    sf::Event event;
    float dt;
    bool run=true;
    glClearColor(50/255.0f, 75/255.0f, 50/255.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    while(run){
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
            if(event.type==sf::Event::Closed)run=false;
        glRotatef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, part of the object disappears:

[image]

Is there a way to increase the viewing distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL assumes a max in any dimension from -1 to 1, so you need to normalize your values relative to that.

ex you have a line segment from 0,0,-2.0 to 0,0,-32.3: (assuming -z away from camera)
you would have to scale each vector to fit accordingly:

```
p1 := {0, 0, -2.0}
p2 := {0, 0, -32.3}
p2len := length(p2) //In this case just 32.3
p1 := {p1.x / p2len, p1.y / p2len, p1.z / p2len} // {0, 0, -0.0619}
p2 := {p2.x / p2len, p2.y / p2len, p2.z / p2len} // {0, 0, -1}
```

Comment: but is there a way to increase opengl's max dimensions?

Comment: @RoyVaron Not that I know of. but you can represent almost any range of values with the mathematics... Also have you tried removing the glTranslate(...) call?

Comment: @RoyVaron https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFrustum.xml
Or google for glFrustrum

Answer (score 1):

Just change the one before the last glVertex call, from:
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f);
to
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

and then, please, please, read this:

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-opengl.php

Comment: it didn't work, it just changed the geometry, and part of the object is still not visible.

Comment: Now I see it. You are rotating the scene. So you have to configure the the view matrix yourself and not use the SFML default that is ortho view. Read my link to see how. More or less what is happening: SFML configures a "2D" view, but you want a 3D view, so you need to push his matrix view, set yours, render, pop SFML matrix.